# CI inisist on minitest seed on next run

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, minitest, circleci, order-of-execution

We have CircleCI that runs rake tests on every git push to GitHub.
We use mintest on a rails cbra application.

My last "build" failed. I believe it's because of the order of execution.
The build log says "Run options: --seed 23914"

How do insist that the next git push (that push contains several other fixes for tests) be built/tested with the same seed "--seed 23914"